# Gem5 in full system running spec2006 runs out of memory

Tags: simulation, benchmarking, gem5

What I am trying to do is run a spec2006 benchmark (namely the 410.bwaves one) in full system mode. 
I have made a .rcS script to pass to the fs.py script and the command I type to start the simulation is as follows:

```
build/X86/gem5.opt configs/example/fs.py --script="../run_bwaves.rcS"  --disk-image=ubuntu-14.04.img --kernel=x86_64-vmlinux-2.6.22.9
```

The result after some time is:

```
Free swap:            0kB
131072 pages of RAM
3650 reserved pages
18 pages shared
0 pages swap cached
Out of memory: kill process 807 (bwaves) score 13154 or a child
Killed process 807 (bwaves)
/tmp/script: line 39:   807 Killed                  ./bwaves
```

[Full linux output here](https://pastebin.com/GifAxkeC) 
[Gem5 output here](https://pastebin.com/DTfEigzq)

I am guessing it has something to do with this line: `warn: DRAM device capacity (8192 Mbytes) does not match the address range assigned (512 Mbytes)`
but I am not sure.

I have tried adding a `--mem-size=...` flag but it brakes the simulation with a `Memory size not divisible by page size` error.
If anyone could help me I would be glad.

Edit: As suggested by comment, I used a large enough `--mem-size` flag divisible by the page size. The error now has turned into

```
bwaves[807]: segfault at 00007ffee647624c rip 0000000000410eb5 rsp 00007fff664761c0 error 4
/tmp/script: line 39:   807 Segmentation fault      ./bwaves
```

Comment: 131072 x 4k page size (I'm assuming) is only 512 MiB, so yeah, that's not much for SPEC CPU2006.  Did you specify a memory size that was a multiple of 4096?

Comment: Probably no, I am going to try it, but in this case the problem would not be the mem size, but the address range which I don't really know how to change.